# Execute linq expression

Tags: c#, linq

I have written a query like this

```
            var tmpQuery = (from items x in items
                            from items2 y in items2
                            select sb.AppendLine(string.Format(format, y.Name)));
```

How can I execute this query? I don't want the result, I would like to have only the execution.

Thank's

Comment: If you are looking for the underlying SQL you can view tmpQuery in the debugger and drill into it to retrieve the DB query.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Please describe the desired behaviour in natural language.

Comment: @Robert I would like execute sb.AppendLine(string.Format(format, y.Name))

Comment: Did you try sth like this:
foreach(var item in tmpQuery );

Comment: If I understand correctly, you don't want "a list of results", but add those results directly to the StringBuilder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot execute a query without getting the result - queries build results.  What you appear to be trying to do is execute code in a loop, not build a query.  If you want to execute code in a loop write a loop and leave linq for actual queries:

e.g. use:

```
 for (x in items) {
      for (y in items2) {
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format(format, y.Name);
      }
 }
```

Comment: I would like to use linq instead foreach because I red this improvement on a C# book. But I'didnt find out how to execute a query

Comment: A linq query is executed when you iterate over it using `foreach`  or when calling a function list `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()`.  However in your case you don't want a list or array you want to append lines to a `StringBuilder`.  You have an action not a query so what you are doing is not a good fit for linq.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
(from items x in items
  from items2 y in items2
  select y.Name)
.ToList()
.ForEach(s => sb.AppendLine(string.Format(format, s)));
```

Notice the ToList() inbetween to convert the query to a `List<T>`, which has a [ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) method.

**EDIT**
But note (as noted in the comments) that this will create an extra intermediate list that you will not have when you just use a `foreach` to loop through the iterator (the "from" expression with just a "select y").

Comment: Why should you take the effort (in terms of time and memory) of building a list when you can directly `for each` the query?

Comment: You execute the query with a ToList() in front of it twitce. This is ineffecient. you could just use the Foreach around the linq expression. 
Sth like this:
'foreach(var item in (from items x in items
                                from items2 y in items2
                               select sb.AppendLine(string.Format(format, y.Name))); '
But I don't know if this is good practice either